# Refresh app when it connects to Internet

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

At the moment if I launch my app without an internet connection the screen just launches white.

Then when you get an internet connection and launch the app again it will still remain white (unless you close the app completely and launch the app with internet connection.)

So I want to be able make some sort of holding page that will display there is no internet connection and then once the app launches again with connection it will automatically refresh or re-direct the page with the correct content.

I want to know is there anyway of refreshing View Controllers? I can only see it for table view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

To refresh your own view controller, just write your own update routine. E.g.

```
func upateUI(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
   nameLabel?.text = data["name"] as? String
   mySwitch.on = data["active"] as! Int > 0
   // etc.
}
```

One common way is to use `NSNotification` to alert any visible view. Just register for the notification via `NSNotificationCenter` when it becomes visible and deregister when it goes off-screen.

Comment: Then maybe you should explain what you want more clearly.

Comment: Never meant it in a rude way. The NSNotification is a good idea thou, thanks.